# `public_decrypt': padding check failed (OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError)

Tags: ruby, openssl

Im trying to decrypt using a public key.

```
bob = TCPSocket.open(host, port)

cs_public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read 'c_public_key.pem'

puts "Alice is connected to bob"

bobs_public_key = ""
while line = bob.gets # Read lines from socket
  bobs_public_key = bobs_public_key + line   # and build them
end

bobs_public_key = JSON.parse(bobs_public_key)

puts "Alice recieved Bob's Public Key:"
puts bobs_public_key["key"]

#Error is on this line.
decypted = cs_public_key.public_decrypt(Base64.decode64(bobs_public_key["digest"])) 

puts decypted
```

and am getting the error: `'public_decrypt': padding check failed (OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError)`

Can someone explain what this error means and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error recently and tracked it down the the padding algorithm used, `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` is defaulting to `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING`, but the message was generated in another system that defaulted to using the perfered `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`. The public/private encrypt/decrypt methods all take an optional second argument to set the padding, and this fixed the issue for me.

```rb
rsa.private_decrypt encrypted_text, OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was encrypting the digest using the wrong private key, so that public key was unable to decrypt it and threw that error.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the data you are trying to decrypt with Public key should be encrypted data. From the code, it looks like you are passing plain text instead of encrypted data.

Make sure that `bobs_public_key["digest"]` is encrypted. Generally it is signature of the data which is encrypted and that is to be passed. Check if your data has signature.

You are getting padding error because in RSA encryption, data is treated as a big number whatever is there in binary and then its power is raised and there is some padding. For plain text or slightly modified data, that padding check may fail.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this padding issue while trying to decrypt the key using openssl command.

openssl rsautl  -decrypt -in key_raw -inkey SIT_private.pem

RSA operation error
16764:error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error:../openssl-1.1.1k/crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:251:
16764:error:04065072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check failed:../openssl-1.1.1k/crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:491:

In my case using **-oaep** option solved the problem.

openssl rsautl  -decrypt -in key_raw -inkey SIT_private.pem -oaep